# Visual Drag & Drop image in HTML inline

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a script that will allow a user to pick an image in an HTML page and drag it to a new location while allowing the other page's element to align around it.

While dragging the image should be completely visible (there are many scripts, like **TinyMCE** and **CKeditor**) which don't show the image while dragging and only show its new location and the elements around the dragged image after dropping it.

And just to be clear, the image is using the same `z-index` as the rest of the page (its inline).

I hope I was clear enough, let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Something like jQuery Masonry? http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Nope. Don't see anything related to drag & drop option, it simply seems like its changing the layout according to screen size.

Comment: You can use jQuery UI's draggable in conjunction with masonry to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure this is as straight forward as you suggest. I don't see any way combine the both to achieve a drag and drop effect that will allow, for example, to drag an element inside out side a DIV to be inside of it and then move it outside of the DIV again. This need to work on any tag, e.g dragging an image around a page to position it inside a table cell (TD) or a DIV, or a paragraph.